# How can source files containing specific content be excluded from a srcSet in Gradle (using Kotlin DSL)

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'd like to exclude some tests from a srcSet in Gradle. Basically integration tests and unit tests have been mixed up (there are thousands).

I can tell which is which by looking at the content.

If the content contains some specific code I know it's an integration test.

How can I modify a srcSet like this:

```
sourceSets {
    val test by getting
    test.java.srcDirs("src")
}
```

to exclude certain files by content ?

Comment: I wouldn't use a SourceSet. Instead, I would use an exclude on the test task: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:exclude(org.gradle.api.specs.Spec)

Comment: But if it's a mess, and if you write code to distinguish integration tests from unit tests anyway, why not use that code to move them to a separate directory, and clean the mess?